# git log, show the dates in a usable format?

Tags: git

Somebody has already formulated this alias for our git log:

```
git log --graph --abbrev-commit \
    --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'
```

However, this shows `5 days ago` rather than `02/12/2018 16:47:00`

I tried adding `--date=local` but it didn't make any difference.

How can I change the above to show the datetime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The formats manual suggests](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) that you use `%cd` in place of `%cr` to get a timestamp respected by the `--date` format, which you can then set independently of this invocation.

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cd) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```

The above produces a timestamp in the form of Wed Oct 17 15:51:57 2018 -0600 for me.